# It is possible to filter the array that have duplicate character in its element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Question
Is is possible, to match a word that contains the same character in different positions of string array?

**for example:**- suppose i have the following array

```
arr1=["apply","application","apple","alphabet","killo","pipe"]
```

Now I want the following output of the element that have double 'p' (may be together or different position)

**Desirable output**:

```
arr1=["apply","application","apple","pipe"]
```

if i put 'l' then I should get **output** `arr1=[killo]` output

```
arr1=["apply","application","apple","alphabet","killo","pipe"]    
ans= arr1.filter(x => x.includes('p'))  
console.log(ans)
```

but i am getting following output

```
arr1=["apply","application","apple","alphabet","pipe"]
```

Comment: the question you have mentioned is filtering the duplicate value of array and my question is totally different from that question. I want to filter the array that have repeating letter in its word. I need repeating letter words in the array only!

Comment: I'm sure there will be another duplicate. Have you tried google?

Comment: I am doing google from last 5 hour but did not find the solution please help me sir. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to work on your google skills if you spent 5 hours looking but didn't find that. Literally search for `list get duplicates javascript`, top result...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex format:

```js
var arr1 = ["apply", "application", "apple", "alphabet", "killo", "pipe"];

function filter_dup(arr, c) {
  return arr.filter(x => x.match(new RegExp(`.*${c}.*${c}.*`)));
}

console.log(filter_dup(arr1, 'p'));
console.log(filter_dup(arr1, 'l'));
```

You can also use `String.prototype.indexOf` and `String.prototype.lastIndexOf` (if the first and last indices of a character are different than there are at least two occurrences of that character):

```js
var arr1 = ["apply", "application", "apple", "alphabet", "killo", "pipe"];

function filter_dup(arr, c) {
  return arr.filter(x => x.indexOf(c) != x.lastIndexOf(c));
}

console.log(filter_dup(arr1, 'p'));
console.log(filter_dup(arr1, 'l'));
```

Comment: but instead of 'p' I want to use the variable in the regex.. can you tell me how i can achieve that. Like let char1='p' and now i want that char1 variable

Comment: @Arunsharma way ahead of you, it's now a function that you can pass a variable into.

Comment: MrGeet  console.log(arr1.filter(x => x.match(/.*Char1.*Char1.*/)));  like that?

Comment: @Arunsharma no, I have modified my answer, there is a function now, `filter_dup(arr1, Char1)`.